# ValueError: 'cri_usm_demuxer\decrypt.pyx' doesn't match any files

Tags: github, installation, cython, valueerror, cythonize

Im just a random person who dont know python and tried to install something but i had facing a problem...

when I type this

```
python PyCriUsm-main build_ext --inplace
```

It give me a respond like this and i dont know how to fix this it seem like it is a serious plobrem...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\User\PyCriUsm-main\__main__.py", line 10, in <module>
    ext_modules=cythonize(Extension("decrypt", ["decrypt.pyx"])),
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 1010, in cythonize
    module_list, module_metadata = create_extension_list(
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 845, in create_extension_list
    for file in nonempty(sorted(extended_iglob(filepattern)), "'%s' doesn't match any files" % filepattern):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 117, in nonempty
    raise ValueError(error_msg)
ValueError: 'decrypt.pyx' doesn't match any files
```

so how can i fix this...
waiting for respond, thanks a lot for the person who lend me a hand.

*other detail:
"**main**.py"

```
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from distutils.extension import Extension

setup(
    name='PyCriUsm',
    version='0.1.0',
    description='A Module to decrypt CRIUSM video files',
    author='unipendix',
    ext_modules=cythonize(Extension("decrypt", ["cri_usm_demuxer\decrypt.pyx"])),
    zip_safe=False,)
```

full code: https://github.com/BUnipendix/PyCriUsm
*

Im just a "baby" to Python and Cython, so I am not able take any useful action, but i still try to learn.